# Powershell Script to join two function results based on common key columns

Tags: powershell

Could someone provide a PowerShell script to join two function results based on common key columns.

Example:

Result1 and Result2 has common field 'Name'. I want to join both the results and fetch the below informations.

```
$Result1 = get-wmiobject -ComputerName localhost -Class win32_service
$Result2 = get-service
```

Result

```
Name        : wuauserv
DisplayName : Windows Update
Status      : Running
StartMode   : Manual
ProcessId   : 400
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below PowerShell script to join both the results based on common key column (Name).

```
$Result1=get-wmiobject -ComputerName localhost -Class win32_service
$Result2=get-service 
$Result=@()
for($i=0;$i -lt $Result2.count;$i++)
{
   $startmode=($Result1 | where{$_.Name -eq $Result2[$i].Name})|Select StartMode,ProcessId
   $tempObj=new-object PSObject
   $tempObj | Add-member noteproperty Name $Result2[$i].Name
   $tempObj | Add-member noteproperty DisplayName $Result2[$i].DisplayName
   $tempObj | Add-member noteproperty Status $Result2[$i].Status
   $tempObj | Add-member noteproperty StartMode $startmode.StartMode
   $tempObj | Add-member noteproperty ProcessId $startmode.ProcessId

   $Result += $tempObj
}
$Result
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to combine the output of the two commands. All of the properties are already out from the `Get-WMIObject`. (Personally I like using the CIM cmdlets instead of WMI wherever possible too)

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Service | select Name, DisplayName, State, StartMode, ProcessId
```

Edit: The output of State from `gcim` is the Status property of `Get-Service` (Here's a calculated property to fix that, if that's an issue)

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Service | select Name, DisplayName, @{Name="Status";Expression={$_.State}}, StartMode, ProcessId
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $result=get-wmiobject -ComputerName localhost -Class win32_service | %{ New-Object psobject -Property @{ objectwmi=$_; objectgetservice=(get-service | where name -eq $_.Name | select -first 1)}    }
```